# Android: How to use List of String arrays inside List row

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am struggling with my custom listview. I want to populate my list view with my custom `row.xml` file which contains five textviews. I have a text file `mytextfile.txt` in the `raw` folder. It look like this:

```
SUN-9-JULY-On Sale Now-New York, Time Square
SAT-15-JULY-On Sale Now-London, National Gallery
MON-23-JULY-On Sale Now-Paris, The Eiffel Tower
// More lines here...
```

As you can see I create a string array from each line (using split method with "-") and put all string arrays inside a `ArrayList`. I don't know how to create my `CustomAdapter` class to make this work. My other files looks like...

Concerts.java

```
public class Concerts {

    private List<String[]> mAllConcerts;

    public List<String[]> getAllConcerts() {
        return mAllConcerts;
    }

    public Concerts() {
        mAllConcerts = new ArrayList<>();
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        InputStreamReader inputReader = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        String line;
        try {
            inputStream = MainActivity.getGlobalContext().getResources()
                    .openRawResource(R.raw.mytextfile.txt);
            inputReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
            while (( line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String [] mConcertDetails = line.split("-");
                mAllConcerts.add(mConcertDetails);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // cathing...
        }
        finally {
             // closing...
        }
    }
}
```

CustomAdapter.java (I don't even know if I am on the right path here)

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    TextView concertDayName;
    TextView concertDayNumber;
    TextView concertMonthName;
    TextView concertOnSaleNow;
    TextView concertPlaceName;

    Concerts concerts;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.concert_row, values);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.concert_row, parent, false);

        concerts = new Concerts();

        concertDayName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.concert_day_name);
        concertDayNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.concert_day_number);
        concertMonthName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.concert_month_name);
        concertOnSaleNow = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.concert_on_sale_now);
        concertPlaceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.concert_place_name);

        for(int i = 0; i < concerts.getAllConcerts().size(); i++) {
            String[] concertRow = concerts.getAllConcerts().get(i);
            concertDayName.setText(concertRow[0]);
            concertDayNumber.setText(concertRow[1]);
            concertMonthName.setText(concertRow[2]);
            concertOnSaleNow.setText(concertRow[3]);
            concertPlaceName.setText(concertRow[4]);
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

MenuConcerts.java (This is the fragment that list will be shown)

```
public class MenuConcerts extends Fragment {

    String[] concertDetails;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.concerts_layout, container, false);

        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle(getString(R.string.title_spelningar));

        ListAdapter listAdapter = new CustomerAdapter(getActivity(), concertDetails);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think a better approach would be to create a `Concert` class, and instead of `private List<String[]> mAllConcerts;` you would have `private List<Concert> mAllConcerts;`

Comment: @DanielNugent hi, how should I get all string values from text file into that Concert entity class? Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you do a CustomAdapter with an ArrayList of objects instead of an array of string arrays:

```
Public Class Concert {
private String dayName;
private String dayNumber;
// constructors, getter and setters
}
```

So you just do:

```
   public class CustomAdapterextends BaseAdapter {

Context context;

protected List<Concert> listConcert;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public ListCarsAdapter(Context context, List<Concert> listConcert) {
    this.listConcert= listConcert;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;
}

public int getCount() {
    return listConcert.size();
}

public Concert getItem(int position) {
    return listConcert.get(position);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.concert_row,parent, false);

        holder.concertDayName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.concert_day_name);
        holder.concertDayNumber= (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.concert_day_number);
        holder.concertMonthName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.concert_month_name);
        holder.concertOnSaleNow = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.concert_on_sale_now);
        holder.concertPlaceName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.concert_place_name);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Concert concert = listConcert.get(position);
    holder.concertDayName .setText(concert.getDayName());
    holder.concertDayNumber.setText(concert.getDayNumber());
    //etc.
    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView concertDayName;
    TextView concertDayNumber;
    Textview concertMonthName;
    Textview concertOnSaleNow;
    Textview concertPlaceName;
}

}
```

And your activity:

```
public class MenuConcerts extends Fragment {

ArrayList<Concert> arrayConcert = new ArrayList<Concert>();


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.concerts_layout, container, false);

        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle(getString(R.string.title_spelningar));
 // all the reading file logic here;
        ListAdapter listAdapter = new CustomerAdapter(getActivity(), arrayConcert);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your solution but I don't see you are using my `Concerts.java` class which reads from `mytextfile.txt`. How should I get those values from text file? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @oxyt from what I think, you should read the file from a method of the activity, not the Concert class,  if you still want to add that method to your class, you can. But put the attributes that they have too.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I finally made it work! :) I did miss your comment (// all the reading file logic here) in MenuConcerts class before. Just saw it and added a method in that class and it's all good now... Thanks to all of you guyz!

Answer (score 1):

1. Where is your `ListView`? You dont init it in `onCreateView` method and you need to set `listAdapter` to `ListView`.
2. In `CustomAdapter` `getView` method you don't need to inflate view from xml all times. You must to reuse created view. Check `convertView`:

   `if(convertView ==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
           convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.concert_row, parent, false);
   }`
3. For your `TextView's` in adapter is better to use ViewHilder pattern -  [Example](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html)
4. You don't need this cycle:

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i < concerts.getAllConcerts().size(); i++) {
           String[] concertRow = concerts.getAllConcerts().get(i);}
   ```

use only `String[] concertRow = concerts.getAllConcerts().get(position);` and then set your text to text fields, because in `getView` method only one `ListView` row is created.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... Helped me to understand how bad I am at this :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should extends `BaseAdapter`, not `ArrayAdapter`.
In method `getView` you can inflate your `row.xml` layout. And findById all your TextViews.

[Here](https://github.com/RediOne1/android-lab-4/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/androidlab4) is my sample app with custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a list view in your fragment XML file (I'm assuming the view you inflate is that). Then you assign a ID to it (I'll use `R.id.list` as an example). Once you got that call (in the onCreateView:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
// set the adapter
lv.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

And you should be good.